# React goes back to initial state after POST ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I'm very new to reactjs, and I'm having quite a bit of an issue getting my state to update after a POST request to my server. Right now I have a page that shows a list of notes and a simple form where you can add a note.

The problem is when I put text in the textbox and and submit the form, it makes the request and updates the state for a split second, then goes back to the original state. I'm populating the component right now using hardcoded json data just to see this component work. Is the entire app refreshing after the network call? Why?

I realize I can probably make a GET request at componentDidMount to make sure the app is always updated, but why should I have to make two requests every time this component is rendered? Can't I just make the POST request and if it's a 200, update the state?

Here is my form component:

```
class NewNoteForm extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(note) {
    if (this.note.value) {
      this.props.handleClick(this.note.value)
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <form>
        <textarea ref={input => this.note = input} id="note"></textarea>
        <button id="submit-note" onClick={() => { this.handleSubmit(this.note) }}>Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the parent component that renders the form:

```
class Incident extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      showAddNoteForm: false,
      notes: []
    };

    this.showNewNoteForm = this.showNewNoteForm.bind(this);
    this.handleNewNoteSubmission = this.handleNewNoteSubmission.bind(this);
  }

  showNewNoteForm() {
    this.setState({
      showAddNoteForm: true
    });
  }

  handleNewNoteSubmission (noteContent) {
    axios.post('/incidents/note')
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          notes: this.state.notes.concat({
            'id': 123,
            'created_user': 'brian',
            'created_at': new Date().toISOString(),
            'note': noteContent
          })
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 data-id="incident-header">Incident #{this.props.incident.id}</h1>

        <div>
          <h3>Notes</h3>
          <button onClick={this.showNewNoteForm} id="show-note">Add Note</button>
        </div>

        {this.state.showAddNoteForm && <NewNoteForm handleClick={this.handleNewNoteSubmission}/>}

        <div data-id='incident-notes'>
        {
          this.state.notes.map( note => {
            let noteDetails = {
              'id' : note.id,
              'content' : note.note,
              'created_user' : note.created_user,
              'created_at' : this.getDateString(note.created_at)
            };
            return <Note key={note.id} details={noteDetails} />;
          })
        }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with forms, submitting them triggers an event (POST action by default) that is causing the page to refresh, thus you lose your updated state.
You might have two solutions to that problem:

1. Change the button type from submit(default) to button, so pressing the button no longer cause the form to be submitted.
2. Prevent the action from refreshing the page. You can handle the event triggered by submit: `onClick={(event) => { event.preventDefault();this.handleSubmit(this.note) }}`
   This should also allow you to submit the form by pressing enter in the textarea, as the submit action will no longer refresh you page and reaload the whole react code.

Comment: answer is correct, but please NEVER do an onClick like that... writing it in an ordered function would take 2 more seconds and make the code readable. also since its in the render function Im pretty sure that the function will be recreated every time you update ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the only issue but you have to change this `setState`

```
this.setState({
  notes: this.state.notes.concat({
    'id': 123,
    'created_user': 'brian',
    'created_at': new Date().toISOString(),
    'note': noteContent
  })
});
```

to

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  notes: prevState.notes.concat({
    'id': 123,
    'created_user': 'brian',
    'created_at': new Date().toISOString(),
    'note': noteContent
  })
}));
```

When you use the the previous state (or props) to update the state, you need to use the function parameter version or you could deal with stale data

Comment: I have actually tried this, but it still does it. The other guy who answered actually solved my issue. The problem was because I didn't specify the button type to be of type button. It was defaulting to "submit" and thus causing a refresh of my app.

Comment: Yeah, I see, but anyway, you need this in any case. I mean, maybe sometimes work, sometimes not. You can't know. Just stick to this rule.

Comment: I will change this. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I gave you an upvote for the good information :)

Comment: You're welcome. Here a link https://medium.com/@wisecobbler/using-a-function-in-setstate-instead-of-an-object-1f5cfd6e55d1